# Get changesets from multiple users in TFS between specified dates

Tags: tfs

I want to look at every changesets my team did between specified dates for the entire project that we're working on. Currently, I can only look at each set of changes by each individual. Is this feasible?

Comment: `tf history $/Project/ /version:"D2012-12-1~2013-12-1" /collection:http://tfs/collection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your filter based on `User Field` `(@Me Macro)` of your `query WIQL`. create query just on `ChangeSet` value for `workitem type filter`